# How to stop multiple threads in the sling threadpool from executing the same statement?

Tags: java, multithreading, aem

How do I prevent threads in the sling threadpool from executing the statement: serv.getService().start( tic, info ); 
multiple times if the execution has already been completed by one thread?

I tried using a flag, _alreadyExecuted but that does not seem to help.

Log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8jZw.png

My code is as follows,

```
     private void sendBlock( service serv, String tic, Resource block, 
     Update update, Info info, ResourceResolver resolver ) throws 
     IOException {
     private Boolean _alreadyExecuted = Boolean.FALSE;
     if( tic != null ) {
        String tic = null;
        if(!_alreadyExecuted){
             getLogger().info("Before startSubmission. Currently _alreadyexecuted is " +_alreadyExecuted);
             serv.getService().start( tic, info );
             getLogger().info("After startSubmission, _alreadyexecuted is about to change to true. Currently _alreadyexecuted is " +_alreadyExecuted);
             _alreadyExecuted = Boolean.TRUE;
             getLogger().info("After startSubmission, _alreadyexecuted has been changed to true. Currently _alreadyexecuted is " +_alreadyExecuted);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know your question has already been answered but may I ask what your use case was? I've never come across the need to use volatile in my AEM projects.

Comment: While processing the job, two threads from the job thread pool were executing the same statement resulting in duplicate requests. This was causing a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the field to `volatile`:

```
 private volatile Boolean _alreadyExecuted = Boolean.FALSE;
```

In a multi-threaded execution environment, threads are allowed cache the value of a field (and usually do). The `volatile` keyword ensures all threads use the current (same) value assigned to the field.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response. It worked for me!